# Drupal Registration Form In Lightbox With Ajax

Tags: ajax, users, javascript

I updated my post up top to pull in the user form created in Drupal, it now loads it in a lightbox correctly, how can I submit this using AJAX, validate this all in the Lightbox? any ideas?

Any help would be good help :)

```
    <?php
function ajax_register_menu() {
  $items['request'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'ajax_register_mypage',
    'page arguments' => array('ajax_register_form'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'title' => t('MY TITLE'),
  );

  $items['request/submit'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'ajax_register_submit',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access callback' => FALSE,
  );

  return $items;
}

function ajax_register_mypage($form){
    print '<div style="background: #FFFFFF;">';
    print 'Hello World';
    print render(drupal_get_form('user_register_form'));
    print '</div>';
}

function ajax_register_submit() {
    $returnO = new StdClass();
    $returnO->status = true;
    $returnO->message = 'MY INFORMATIVE MESSAGE HERE';

    print drupal_json($returnO);

    die;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I recall correctly, instead of calling render() for your drupal_get_form(), call drupal_render() instead.

```
<?php 

function ajax_register_mypage($form){
  print 'Hello World';
  print drupal_render(drupal_get_form($form));
}

?>
```

Hope this ends up solving your issue on this one.

Comment: `render()` is just a wrapper that calls `drupal_render()` internally. The only difference is that `render()` checks to see if the argument is an array. If so, it passes through `drupal_render()`, if not it just returns the variable as-is. using either function on a form array will produce exactly the same results

Comment: I updated my post up top to pull in the user form created in Drupal, it now loads it in a lightbox correctly, how can I submit this using AJAX, validate this all in the Lightbox? any ideas?